# How can I recognize the data in Linking.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

First, i input nickname to nick in inputs. Second, get url data through Linking.openURL('http://10.0.2.2:3065/auth/kakao'). Third, when Linking.addEventListener is executed,  I would like to have the nick I typed in to be recorded in console.log("nick:",).

But when I run my code it writes nick: undifned.

how can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
            const Kakao = () => {

            const [nick, onChangeNick] = useInput('');    

            useEffect(() => {
                Linking.addEventListener('url', async ({url, nick}) => {
                console.log('nick::', nick);                                               //third


                });
                return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url');
            }, []);



            return (
                <Container>
                    <Inputs placeholder="닉네임" value={nick} onChange={onChangeNick} />           //first

                    <LoginButton
                    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://10.0.2.2:3065/auth/kakao')}>        //second 
                    <Label>카카오 로그인 링크</Label>
                </LoginButton>
                
                </Container>
            );
            };

            export default Kakao;
```

Answer (score 0):

> First, I don't know exactly what is `Linking`, if it is an external
> library or something (maybe sharing some context about could help).
>
> Second, you are trying to access to `nick` on `useEffect` inside of a
> callback function of `Linking` and as a destructured object of the
> *parameter*. **Check this point.**

**EDIT:**
I just readed the docs about `Linking` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#handling-deep-links)

You simply don't have a parameter called `nick` in the callback of `addEventListener`.
Just **remove** it and it will get the `nick` from state because it is in a global scope.

```js
            const [nick, onChangeNick] = useInput('');    

            useEffect(() => {
// Remove `nick`
                Linking.addEventListener('url', async ({url}) => { 
                console.log('nick::', nick);                                               //third


                });
                return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url');
            }, []);
```